# anchor tag won't accept left clicks

Tags: html, cs-cart

I'm building out a site using CS Cart. There's a link in the header to show the cart contents. You click that and then there is a dropdown showing what's in your cart. You then click an item, or the "no items in cart" in the dropdown and you go to your shopping cart page showing you what's in your cart. All pretty basic stuff...

...except when you left-click on the item to go to your cart page, the link doesn't work. BUT, if you right-click and "open in new tab" that works.

You can view it here: 75.102.37.23/about-us.html

This seems like a very silly question with probably a silly answer, but I'm stumped.

**UPDATE:** NM, I deleted all of the blocks in the header area and rebuilt it and now it's working. Still not sure what was causing the issue, but thank's for the help all!

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/)

Comment: It appears to be an issue with CS Cart.  They seem to have scripted  the popup to disappear on click.  Best bet is to contact the developer.

Comment: @nullability It does this in Chrome, FF, and IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is almost certainly that you're calling `event.preventDefault()` in the functionality that closes this dropdown again. This must be somewhere in a click handler for this link or one of the parent or child elements.

Comment: From what I understand CS Cart uses pure CSS for their dropdowns. I did go through the JS anyway but couldn't find the preventDefault()

Comment: @Ant I searched with firebug and I found several in `core.js`.

Comment: hmm... must have missed it. i look into that. thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that, MD! :)